# How to keep TCP sockets open?

Tags: java, tcp

Our application has a ping-pong like conversation with many servers (each server has a corresponding thread where those connections are made). Code below works, but it opens a new connection for every new request and is used only once, which soon leads to reaching max connection cap set by server.

DataProvider.java

```
public static ZnResult sendTcpQuery(String xml, String url, int port) {
    List<ZnXmlResult> results = new ArrayList<>();
    String xmlString = xml != null ? new String((xml + "\n").getBytes()) : "";
    int error = ZnResult.OK;
    try (Socket clientSocket = new Socket(url, port)) {
        clientSocket.setSoTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        try (BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"))) {
            outToServer.writeBytes(xmlString);
            try (StringWriter responseFromServer = new StringWriter()) {
                String readLine;
                while ((readLine = inFromServer.readLine()) != null) {
                    ...
                }
            }
            outToServer.close();
            clientSocket.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOG.error("Exception {}", url + ":" + port, ex);
        error = ZnResult.ERR;
    }
    return error == ZnResult.OK ? new ZnResult(results) : new ZnResult(error);
}
```

How can I transform it, so everything can be done within one connection?
I figured I would do something like this:

SocketFactory.java

```
public class SocketFactory {
private static HashMap<String, Socket> socketsByAddress = new HashMap<>();
private static HashMap<Socket, DataOutputStream> outputStreamsBySocket = new HashMap<>();
private static HashMap<Socket, BufferedReader> readersBySocket = new HashMap<>();

public static Socket getSocket(String address) {
    String ip = Tools.getIpFromAddress(address);
    int port = Tools.getPortFromAddress(address);
    Socket socket = socketsByAddress.get(address);
    if (socket == null) {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(ip, port);
            socket.setSoTimeout(60000);
            socketsByAddress.put(address, socket);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SocketFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    return socket;
}

public static DataOutputStream getOutputStream(Socket socket) {
    DataOutputStream outputStream = outputStreamsBySocket.get(socket);
    if (outputStream == null) {
        try {
            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            outputStreamsBySocket.put(socket, outputStream);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SocketFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    return outputStream;
}

public static BufferedReader getReader(Socket socket) {
    BufferedReader reader = readersBySocket.get(socket);
    if (reader == null) {
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            readersBySocket.put(socket, reader);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SocketFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    return reader;
}
}
```

DataProvider.java

```
public static ZnResult sendTcpQuery(String xml, String url, int port) {
    List<ZnXmlResult> results = new ArrayList<>();
    int error = ZnResult.OK;
    try {
        String xmlString = xml != null ? new String((xml + "\n").getBytes()) : "";
        Socket clientSocket = SocketFactory.getSocket(url + ":" + port);
        DataOutputStream outToServer = SocketFactory.getOutputStream(clientSocket);
        BufferedReader inFromServer = SocketFactory.getReader(clientSocket);
        outToServer.writeBytes(xmlString);
        try (StringWriter responseFromServer = new StringWriter()) {
            String readLine;
            while ((readLine = inFromServer.readLine()) != null) {
                ...
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOG.error("Exception {}", url + ":" + port, ex);
        error = ZnResult.ERR;
    }
    return error == ZnResult.OK ? new ZnResult(results) : new ZnResult(error);
}
```

but it just doesn't work and only the first one go through.

Comment: Why keep all sockets and streams in HashMap? Also address of your server socket will be the same so only one socket will be kept in the map i think somewhere there is your problem. Leave out HashMap, clientSocket always has its input and output streams. Also 1 client socket should have 1 connection to server socket not multiple.

Comment: I make connections to many servers thus I use HashMap to keep all of them in check..

Comment: Thats nowhere mentioned above, nevermind that. Are you using multiple threads?

Comment: My mistake, I've added it to the description now. Yes, the are multiple threads and every server has a corresponding one.

Comment: Then my advice is to check synchronization since HashMap isnt made for multi threading, take a look at ConcurrentHashMap, otherwise i dont see anything wrong with your code (it still needs some refactoring tho)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop reads until the end of the stream.

```
while ((readLine = inFromServer.readLine()) != null) {
```

A stream only ends once. i.e. you can't end the stream but later use it again.

What you need to do instead;

- have a terminating line which can't occur in your data. e.g. wait for `"[EOF]"`
- send the length of data first and read only that much data.

Comment: Does end of stream close it automatically or do I have to do it myself? Closing the stream closes the associated socket aswell (which would explain my problem), but if it doesn't then why creating a new InputStream with the same socket doesn't work?

Comment: @jarkow You have to close the stream to get an end of stream. Closing the stream in one direction doesn't close the socket or the stream in the other direction.

Comment: @jarkow you can't create a new stream for a socket. You can wrap it with a different wrapper, but the underlying stream is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try to initiate the Socket object using URL rather than IP address as you were doing in your first code and see if it works for you.